# Apply the fixed header effect to a none fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have #header and have #page.

Both are positioned relatively, I don't want to make the header fixed but I want it to overlap the #page.

[image]

The red bit is the #header and the dark green is the #page. I am trying to make the #header overlap the #page but keep the content of the #page away from the #header!

The theory I was trying to apply to make this work is.

**1) find the .outerHeight of #header 
2) Double that height 
3) Apply it as padding-top to the #page
4) Apply the height not doubled as mince margin-top**

Please help, I don't know how to get this working, here is what I have been working with:

```
$(window).on("ready resize", function() {
        if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            var pageTop = $("#header.header-overlay .content").outerHeight() + "px";
            $("#page").css("padding-top", pageTop);
        } else {
            var pageTop = $("#secondHeader").outerHeight() + "px";
            $("#page").css("padding-top", pageTop);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of it. I guess your approach is right

Comment: Cheers mate here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/s83ng74a/1/

Comment: Please make the structure similar to one you want here. That fiddle just had header and page

Comment: #secondHeader what is this?

Comment: on small screen the #headeer will be removed and another #header will appear, this header is for small devices, so the #page will only then have padding-top that is the height of secondHeader

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s83ng74a/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59985/discussion-between-leo-and-sss).

Comment: If your #header height is fixed, why not just add padding-top to your #page inside your css? what are you trying to accomplish? what do you mean by you want them to OVERLAY but keep the content away?

Comment: Any luck with the css changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

> body{  position:relative  }
>
> #header{  position:absolute;  z-index:10;  }
>
> #page{  position:absolute;  top:0;  }

padding-top = calculate height of header.

Also check which div the image is applied as background.